# how to redirect user to web admin interface of my device?

Tags: c, linux, wifi

how to redirect user to web admin interface of my device?

I am using following in my project.

1. httpd of busybox as http server.
2. html files/js/css to create web pages.
3. I don't have any kind of apache like servers.
4. cgi.
5. C language and linux.
6. 16 MB FLASH.

User will connect to device via wifi. When the user want to access the internet via wifi then he should be first redirected to my web page.

The research which I have made is: I need captive portal for this. Truly speaking I have no idea how to implement captive portal and what it is. I have found that wifidog,chilispot and Nocatsplash are such kind of captive portals which are free.

After compiling the wifidog I have found that to run that I need iptables. By doing necessary changes in kernel I am at that stage that I can run wifidog. But when I run the wifidog I have to configure in the wifidog.conf. I have try to do that. I have added some parameters like :

```
ExternalInterface br0,
GatewayInterface br0,
AuthServer {
               Hostname auth.ilesansfil.org
           }
```

I have tried to access my board in which wifidog is running using my browser but I am not getting anything related to wifidog. It just gives my admin page.

One thing is there is no master device in my project. All device should work the same way.

Would anyone please help me on this issue?

Comment: Should I give more information about the issue which I am facing?

Comment: Check the [FAQ], it's better to ask specific questions, for example start down the path you think is best, then when you run into a problem you can't solve bring the code and theroy back here.

Comment: I am sorry if I have asked in a wrong way. I am searching the web for this since last couple of days. The thing is I want to redirect the user to specific web page that is of my device.

Comment: Notice that the answer you got from bluszcz says "yes you are on the right track", that's answers your question, but it's not really helpful right? The key from the faq is `•a specific programming problem`. You said just now in the comments that you `want to redirect the user to specific web page that is of my device` so make an attempt at doing that... if you have no idea where to start very clearly define what you want to do and show your research then after you've updated flag the question to be reopened

Comment: I have edited the question and added the research which I have made. After this research I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far I as understand - yes, you are on right track.

What you need now is AuthPuppy: https://launchpad.net/authpuppy

Comment: I am going to have a 100 devices of its kind. I should use the same firmware on all this devices. should I install it on all the devices?

Comment: I guess you need only one authpuppy share for wifdog

Comment: should this thing be installed on server? I mean I have to create on server which runs this software right? Not on my device because I don't have PHP or sql.

Comment: Yes, you need external server with LAMP stack to install it.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on it. If I get success then I will post the answer on this.